# Excessive qualifying of an enum type

Tags: c++, templates, enums

In this code

```
template<typename ValueT, typename ErrorT = bool>
class ValueOrError
{
private:
    enum class State
    {
        Undefined, OK, EndOfFile, InError
    };
public:
    ........
    template<typename U>
    static ValueOrError
    copyProblem(const ValueOrError<U, ErrorT>& other)
    {
        ValueOrError result;

        result.error_ = other.error_;
        result.state_ = other.state_;
        // result.state_ = static_cast<State>(other.state_);
        return result;
    }

private:
    template<typename U, typename E>
    friend class ValueOrError;

    State  state_;
    ValueT value_;
    ErrorT error_;
};
```

g++ 4.8.3 gives an error at the state assignment. It complains
that a value of type `ValueError<U>::State` cannot be assigned
to a value of type `ValueError<T>::State` for different U and T.
The static cast gets around this.  Is there a better way to
do this?  The State type clearly doesn't vary with the template
parameter.

Answer (score 2):

This is one way:

```
struct State
{
    enum Enum{ Undefined, OK, EndOfFile, InError };
};

template< class ValueT, class ErrorT = bool>
class ValueOrError
    : private State
{
public:
```

Comment: Presumably State would be a class to keep the enum private. I had it separate in an earlier version but I thought that there would be a cleverer way in C++.

Comment: @A.L.Shipman: The `struct` allows the enum identifiers to be used unqualified in `ValueOrError`. It's also a pre-C++11 device for allowing qualified identifiers with standard-compliant compilers. You can't really make the enum totally private (in a practical way!) but you can place it in a namespace called `detail` or `impl` or such (the former is the Boost library convention).